# (Django) Combining auth.User tables with app.UserProfile in Django Rest Framework with Class Based Views

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I need to create `User` instances through the Django Rest API.  The normal Django built-in `User` needs to be extended, most commonly with a `UserProfile` model.  Because of this, `User` objects had to be represented with a separate table for `User` and `UserProfile` in the API.

I assume I could make a single function-based view that combines serialized data from both `User` and `UserProfile` serializers, but I'm really interested to know if it's possible to do the same thing with a class-based view.  It would need to have two querysets and serializer_classes, is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple `APIView` to achieve this:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class GetProfileEmployeeView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # I associate Django users to a matching Employee record via e-mail address
        emp_profile = Employee.objects.get(email=self.request.user.email)
        serializer = EmployeeSerializer(emp_profile)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Then, in your `urls.py` add an endpoint that points to this view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^profile/?$', utility_views.GetProfileEmployeeView.as_view()),
]
```

When users `GET` that endpoint they'll get back their entire user profile. You can also go crazy and manually craft a response that's composed of data from multiple model objects:

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=self.request.employee.id)
    company = toolbox.get_employee_company(employee)

    profile_co = CompanySerializer(company).data
    profile_co['licenses'] = AccountSerializer(Account.objects.get(company=company)).data['license_count']

    profile = {}
    profile['id'] = employee.id
    profile['first_name'] = employee.first_name
    profile['last_name'] = employee.last_name
    profile['email'] = employee.email
    profile['is_admin'] = employee.is_admin
    profile['company'] = profile_co

    return Response(profile)
```